# How to handle a very long bit sequence?

Tags: c, algorithm, binary, sequence, subset

Let us have some sequence A, `{-1, 3, 2, 5}` for example. We can select all its non-empty subsequences using iterations (binary incrementing some iterator) `1 .. 2^|A|`:

```
int i, A[] = {-1, 3, 2, 5};

for (i = 1; i < (1 << sizeof(A)); i++)
{
  int t = i, p = 0;

  while (t > 0)
  {
    if (t % 2 > 0)
      printf("%d\t", a[p]);

    t /= 2, p++;
  }

  printf("\n");
}
```

But what should we do if A contains, for example, 5000000 elements? E.g. how to handle 5-billion-bit number?

Comment: You can use a backtracking algorithm that generates a 0 or 1 for each position and then calls itself recursively for the next one. But there's not much point in doing this for 5 million elements. Maybe you're interested in the k-th lexicographic subsequence?

Comment: Just fyi, 2^5000000 is a 1505152-digit number.

Comment: @ivlad, Thanks, but nope =) I'm interested in ALL subsets (or subsequences - it doesn't really matter how we would call it) =)

Comment: @aioobe, well, the next question will be 'bout this algorithm optimization, for sure =)

Comment: Well good luck with that, because no computer in the world will be able to generate all those during your lifetime.

Comment: @ivlad, i believe, my eeepc would be able to handle this task in a few hours =)

Comment: For 5 million elements? No, it won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is an inerestign set of algorithms that perform such tasks called "Enumeration algorithms". They deal mainly which questions such as: 
1. What is the ith non-empty subset of all subsets ? 
2. Given a non empty subset, what is the next element ? or previous
3. Given a non empty subset, what is the rank of this subset ?

All these operations are performed with linear time. In case you want to obtain all subsets, then you will need to do backtracing.

An interesting book that deals with these issues is: Combinatorial Algorithms, Generation, Enumeration, Search By K. Rossen. 
I have also a set of slides on this topic, I dont know how to attach them though. Check Lucia Moura website, course Combinatorial Algorithms.

(if you need details of any of these algorithms above, let me know please)

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to start optimizing it using CUDA or SSE, like [bitmagic](http://bmagic.sourceforge.net/) does.

you can also test if bytes are totally zero and skip them entirely, and using BSR, BSF and LCZ, you can skip over the bits that are zero and just print out zeros for the amounts of bits skipped.

Comment: I'm sorry for being fooling around, but what are these BSR, BSF and LCZ?

Comment: @shybovycha: Bit Scan Forward & Bit Scan Reverse, these find the first set bit from the MSB or LSB respectively, and Leading Count Zero's, which counts the number of zeros from the MSB(iirc, don't remember this one so well off hand)

Comment: if i'm not mistaken, these work for Visual C++ only (e.g. __BSR and __BSF). Whooh, i hope there are easier ways to do this...

Comment: @shybovycha: They are x86 instructions, both MSVC and gcc have intrinsics for them(they are `_BitScanReverse` and `BitScanReverse` for intrinsic and non-intrinsic versions under VC, x86 assembly uses `BSR`). And on other platforms you can find equivalent instructions, else you can emulate it with bit twiddling. And testing of zero bytes requires nothing more than an `if`